# aws elastiCache for redis **Key-space notification**

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

I'am using aws elastiCache for redis in cluster mode in my project .
I'v used key space notification feature of redis to listen for particular expiry event.It works fine without clustering .But after clustering, I'm unable to get message in subscribe block.

```
subscribe(`__keyevent@0__:expired`);
redis keyspace notification aws elastiCache for redis
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are listening on all nodes

From the manual...

> Events in a cluster

Every node of a Redis cluster generates events about its own subset of the keyspace as described above. However, unlike regular Pub/Sub communication in a cluster, events' notifications are not broadcasted to all nodes. Put differently, keyspace events are node-specific. This means that to receive all keyspace events of a cluster, clients need to subscribe to each of the nodes.

Comment: I tried adding all of the node endpoints as well as the "Configuration endpoint", but the consumer still did not receive the keyspace notifications when the value of the key changed.

I know the consumer is connected because when I manually publish a notification directly to the `__keyspace@0__`-prefaced topic, the consumer receives (and logs) the notification.

Comment: 1 Check event notification enabled. By default keyspace event notifications are disabled because while not very sensible the feature uses some CPU power. Notifications are enabled using the notify-keyspace-events of redis.conf or via the CONFIG SET.
2 Make sure you subscribed to right patterns

Comment: Yes, I enabled the `notify-keyspace-events` and `cluster-enabled` properties in the AWS parameter group.  I have verified the clients are subscribing to the right patterns.

Answer (score 0):

use parameter group in aws to set config and pass the keys in it.